# adding a new language in google trans api python

Tags: google-translate

I'm trying to add my country( senegal ) language(wo = wolof) into googletrans. I already build a list of words, so now I want to integrate them in googletrans python library.
Please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.  The Google Translate APIs are simply a client that send the requests to Google servers where the translation work is actually done.  There is no way to add a new language to the API.  (You can confirm this by looking at the (unofficial) [API source code](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans).)

Besides, you need more than just a word list to do a reasonable job of translating from one language to another.  (Word mapping without any context tends to produce nonsense.)

Having said that ... if you *believe* that you can do reasonable translation based on simple word maps, then you don't need to use Google Translate APIs at all.  You can use your word lists / maps directly in your Python program.

Comment: So what else I  need to do a reasonable job of translating. Do you have any reference please.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
words = {}
words["HELLO"] = "bonjour"
words["I LOVE PYTHON"] = "J'AIME PYTHON"
words["THANK YOU"] = "MERCI"

Comment: "Do you have any reference please." - Not off the top of my head.  It is far too difficult  a problem to "solve" by reading a website.  There are books, research papers, etc on the topic.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are actually just talking about English <-> French translation, the Google Translate API can do that already.

Comment: Thank you !
I am talking about wolof <-> French translation , its not able in google translate.